# How do i get less or more to recognize keystrokes when piping from a cli php script?

Tags: php, unix, command-line

I want to be able to use the arrow keys when i pipe output from a php cli script into less. At the moment php cli does something to the tty which can only be fixed when you execute

```
!stty sane
```

from within less, which is a right pain!

I found a reference to this problem @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#90743 but i can't seem to find an answer :-)

Any help is appreciated, although this problem ranks far below many other problems ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been searching for some tweakable to do exactly this. Right now my best workaround is:

```
php blah.php </dev/null | less
```

which has the desired effect, but is a pita to have to type. It seems that when the PHP CLI detects stdin is a tty, it puts that tty into linemode.

Comment: I think this a very acceptable solution since, although it's a pita, it's also easy to remember :-)

Comment: Couldn't you just do `php < blah.php | less` for the same effect?

Answer (score 2):

If you add `exec('stty cbreak');` to your cli script, it fixes this.  (At least, it does for me, modifying drush.php for this.)

Comment: Only saw this answer just now - it looks like just the thing i'm looking for - Thanks!

Comment: I added a few more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20341430/943279

It might be a PHP bug, and I included my version info for where I had issues and where I didn't in case it really is a PHP bug.

Answer (score 0):

Another options that's slightly more readable (to me) is:

```
less -f <(php whatevz.php)
```

This is also useful when trying to pipe the output of PHP's info flag:

```
less -f <(php -i)
```